# Different server behavior from CURL and browser

Tags: session, curl, dart

My server behaves differently when I do a login request with CURL and from the browser.

When doing the following curl request:

```
 curl -i -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/login' -d 'username=fred&password=blah' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

I get the expected result in form of:
[image: response from curl request]

However when doing the same (or so I think) request from a browser form I see the following result in the browser debugger

[image: canceled request]
[image: canceled request details]

The code of the form used to make the request looks as follows

```
        <form action="localhost:8080/login" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
          <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="submit" id="sign_in" value="Sign In">
        </form>
```

I don't think this is a problem with the Origin of the request since I set `Access-Controll-Allow-Origin': *`.

The entire code of the server can be found [here](https://github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/linkShepherdServer). The code of the client [here](https://github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/linkShepherdClient).

I'am out of ideas. What could cause this problem?

Edit: As suggested by  @Günter Zöchbauer in the comments below it is often necessary to do this sort of form submission via an HttpRequest. I wanted to add a answer with a ready solution to do so, and walked straight into another problem.
The relevant html:

```
  <form id="login_form" action="/login" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" id="sign_in" value="Sign In" on-click="{{submitLogin}}">
  </form>
```

The relevant dart code:

```
  /* Login box */
  login_form = querySelector('#login_form');
  login_form.onSubmit.listen(submitLogin);
```

and

```
/* Login code */
void submitLogin(Event e){
  e.preventDefault();

  FormElement form = e.target as FormElement;
  print('inside of submitLogin');

  Uri loginUri = new Uri(scheme: 'http',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8080,
      path: 'login');

  print(loginUri);
  var request = new HttpRequest();
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  request.request(
      loginUri.toString(),
      method: form.method,
      sendData: new FormData(form)
  ).then(onDataLoaded);
}

void onDataLoaded(HttpRequest req){
  String response = req.responseText;
  print(response);
  //TODO: do visual confiramtion of login
}
```

When comapring the CURL's from the original request (which worked) and the one done by the code above I noticed that the `Content-Type` is different.
I tried to enforce the content type every way I knew but it keeps comming up like.

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/login" -H "Origin: http://localhost:8080" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.0 (Dart) Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryZ1seZo8pq0PZt3Fg" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://localhost:8080/" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data-binary "------WebKitFormBoundaryZ1seZo8pq0PZt3Fg"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""username"""^

"fred"^
"------WebKitFormBoundaryZ1seZo8pq0PZt3Fg"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""password"""^

"blah"^
"------WebKitFormBoundaryZ1seZo8pq0PZt3Fg--"^
"" --compressed
```

Instead of.

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/login" -H "Origin: http://localhost:8080" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.0 (Dart) Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Referer: http://localhost:8080/" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data "username=fred&password=blah" --compressed
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? I can't see one from the screenshot. What should the screenshot tell me? I think you also need to allow the request types `OPTIONS` and `POST` in addition to `Origin` if you want to support CORS requests.

Comment: Try to change the action to "login", "/login" or "http://localhost:8080/login".

Comment: You probably want do a HttpRequest instead posting a form because posting the form leads to a page reload which is usually not what you want in a single page Dart application.

Comment: Chrome developer console -> netowrk tab, right click POST request and select "Copy as cURL" maybe you spot the difference there, if not post it here its probably better than screenshot

Comment: Thanks, @Robert the "/login" solution works. If you want to you can add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer could you please take a look at the newest edit. It is relevant to your comment.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The problem is it does not work. The authenticator `shelf_auth` only handles `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POSTed data. So I can't effortlessly make a few changes on the server side and get this to work. I need to enforce `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` on the client and can't find a way to do so.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm almost there, it works for data not from the form. If you could tell me how to obtain the data from a form as a Map, then I could post a complete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You URL in the `action` attribute is relative that means it is appended to the current hostname. Thus change it to a absolute URL by adding `http://` to it or changing it to `/login` if you're already on `localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer relates to the second part of the question (see the EDIT). I could not find a ready sample code anywhere in the documentation. That's why I add the working code below as an answer. If you find a more elegant way to get the data from the form please write a comment under this post.

HTML part

```
  <form id="login_form" action="/login" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" id="sign_in" value="Sign In">
  </form>
```

The dart code
subscribe to event

```
login_form = querySelector('#login_form');
login_form.onSubmit.listen(submitLogin);
```

event handler

```
/* Login code */
void submitLogin(Event e){
  e.preventDefault();

  FormElement form = e.target as FormElement;
  print('inside of submitLogin');

  Uri loginUri = new Uri(scheme: 'http',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8080,
      path: 'login');
  InputElement username = querySelector('[name="username"]');
  InputElement password = querySelector('[name="password"]');
  Map dataFromForm = {'username':username.value.toString(),'password':password.value.toString()};
  print(loginUri);
  HttpRequest.postFormData(loginUri.toString(), dataFromForm)
  .then(onDataLoaded);
}

void onDataLoaded(HttpRequest req){
  String response = req.responseText;
  print(response);
  //TODO: do visual
```

Comment: it looks fine. Maybe you can use `form.querySelector()` to get the inputs.